# Best way to pass Vuex to instanced component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

What is the best way to pass Vuex to a component instanced programmatically?

This is what I'm doing:

```
let visual = Vue.extend(IPGVisual)
this.tempIPG = new visual({
    propsData: { $store: this.$store }
})
this.tempIPG.$mount()
this.$refs.container.appendChild(this.tempIPG.$el)
this.tempIPG.load()
```

Is that a good approach? It doesn't look beautiful, that's why I suspect that's not a good practice.

Comment: Any component instance already can access Vuex store by doing `this.$store` ...

Comment: @roliroli I had to pass it as prop just because this.$store was undefined

Comment: `this.$store` is undefined on your components?

Comment: Only the ones added programmatically